# Is there any equivalent to import * from 'module' in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I know there is `import {thing} from 'module'` or `const {thing} = require('module')`, and I can also just do `const thing = require('thing')` and use `thing.method()`, but can I, through any tricks available, import all the exports in a module (the way python does `import * from 'lib'`) so that I can just call `method()` without specifying it in the import?

Comment: `import * as methods from 'module'` will create an object named `methods` that contains all exports from the module. There's no way to import and attach directly to the global namespace.

Comment: Damn. :( Well, you can put this as answer so that I can close this.

Comment: Alright, I wrote an answer with a bit of explanation of why this is the case in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to import all exports from a module with the syntax

```
import * as Utils from 'utils';
```

This will create an object called `Utils` which will have all the exports from the `utils` module as its properties.

---

In JS, a scoped variable has to be explicitly declared in that scope. Any reference to a variable that has not been explicitly declared is assumed to be a property of the global namespace. That's why a syntax like `import * from 'module'` can't work as it does in Python. Since the individual imports are not explicitly declared, the only alternative would be to add them as members to the global namespace (in order to be able to access them without a namespace prefix) and that would defeat the purpose of having modules.

Answer (score 1):

import * as methods from 'module' will create an object named methods that contains all exports from the module. There's no way to import and attach directly to the global namespace.  --Very right!